# Why is the candidate composite index not used?

Tags: index, mariadb

Consider the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE `entityusage_trackbyyear` (
  `track_id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `album_id` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `library_id` binary(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstdateofinterval` date NOT NULL,
  `territory_id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `playbacks` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  `userplaybacks` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  `userdownloads` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  `usersingledownloads` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`firstdateofinterval`,`track_id`,`territory_id`),
  KEY `album_id` (`firstdateofinterval`,`album_id`,`territory_id`),
  KEY `library_id` (`firstdateofinterval`,`library_id`,`territory_id`),
  KEY `territory_id` (`firstdateofinterval`,`territory_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the following query :

```
SELECT 
    BIN_TO_UUID(album_id) AS e,
    firstdateofinterval AS p,
    BIN_TO_UUID(territory_id) AS t,
    SUM(playbacks) AS c1,
    SUM(userplaybacks) AS c2,
    SUM(userdownloads) AS c3,
    SUM(usersingledownloads) AS c4
FROM
    entityusage_trackbyyear
WHERE
    firstdateofinterval >= '2018-01-01'
        AND firstdateofinterval <= '2018-09-30'
        AND library_id = UUID_TO_BIN('c72cbb1e-5848-39ee-a201-664f26ee9204')
GROUP BY p , e
```

Why does MariaDB insist on using the `PRIMARY KEY` index, and not the `library_id` index which is a composite index over both `firstdateofinterval` + `library_id` - which are the columns given in the query criteria?

When i explicitly set `USE INDEX (library_id)` it skips using an index entirely.

I must be doing something wrong!

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: entityusage_trackbyyear
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY,album_id,library_id,territory_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 3
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1218204
       r_rows: 685956.00
     filtered: 100.00
   r_filtered: 0.13
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

- The `UUID_TO_BIN` and `BIN_TO_UUID` are functions used to convert UUIDs to / from the "human readable" representation to a compact `binary(16)` data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [FORCE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/force-index/) the index, the optimizer will only then  use your wanted index, else you give it only a hint

```
SELECT 
    BIN_TO_UUID(album_id) AS e,
    firstdateofinterval AS p,
    BIN_TO_UUID(territory_id) AS t,
    SUM(playbacks) AS c1,
    SUM(userplaybacks) AS c2,
    SUM(userdownloads) AS c3,
    SUM(usersingledownloads) AS c4
FROM
    entityusage_trackbyyear
    FORCE INDEX (territory_id)
WHERE
    firstdateofinterval >= '2018-01-01'
        AND firstdateofinterval <= '2018-09-30'
        AND library_id = UUID_TO_BIN('c72cbb1e-5848-39ee-a201-664f26ee9204')
GROUP BY p , e
```

Comment: Thanks @nbk. This is a very obvious index to use. I was under the impression that mariadb will use the most appropriate index, and it puzzles me that it does not even pick that index when given a hint?

Comment: the optimizer has its programming and it works in most cases, with only 1 or two indexes, but with a bunch of them, its algorithms calculate, but as you noticed,  the alghorithm needs much improvement

Comment: @nbk - Why use the `territory_id` index?  It is not even involved in the `WHERE` or `ORDER BY`??

Comment: no particular reason, it was teh first that appeared in view, you have to test them and discard the not used indexes.

Answer (score 1):

- `INDEX(library_id, firstdateofinterval)` will help the query run faster.  Note that the column tested by `=` should be first and the range should be last.
- Why not use the desired index?  Because it won't get past the range.  That is, all 4 of your indexes are equivalent to simply `INDEX(firstdateofinterval)` when you test for a range of dates.
- When you used the "index hint", did it actually run any faster?

Unrelated...  UUIDs are inefficient when the table is bigger than RAM.

Comment: Thanks @Rick James. I will try to redo the index. I know UUIDs are inefficient, but that's just how it is. I can't fix that. However, that is why I've been trying to compact the tables a little by storing the UUIDs as binary.

Comment: @sbrattla - Yes, storing as Binary helps.  For a tiny bonus, consider changing other columns from a 4-byte `INT` to some smaller numeric type.

Comment: Thanks @Rick James, yes, there's actually no reason to use INT(10) . The max value in any of these fields is in the thousands, so a SMALLINT should do.

I assume the "to be" column data type (SMALLINT) will not then prevent me from doing a SUM over the field? That is, the data type of the SUM'ed fields will not be limited to the size of SMALLINT?

Comment: @sbrattla - Valid question; but there is no problem.  `SUM()` and `+` are performed in `BIGINT` (or `DOUBLE`), then stored into the size of the target column.  (`-` and `UNSIGNED` sometimes cause some hiccups.)